# initializing xml variable

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
DECLARE @XML1 XML

SET @XML1=SELECT XMLCOLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ID='123-456'
```

when i do like this i am getting following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Could anyone please help me how to assign xmlcolumn value to xml variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT @XML1= XMLCOLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ID='123-456'
```

Or

```
SET @XML1= (SELECT XMLCOLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ID='123-456')
```

They behave the same if the query returns exactly one row but differ otherwise.

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|    |                        SELECT                         |                   SET                    |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| 0  | No Assignment made. Variable has original value.      | Variable set to null                     |
| 1  | Variable assigned the one matching value              | Variable assigned the one matching value |
| >1 | Variable assigned arbitrary value from matching rows. | Error raised                             |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```